# Java Play 2 - Deployment

Tags: servlets, amazon-web-services, playframework-2.0, war, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

> Updated 08.18.2012

I am using Play 2.0.2 and I want to deploy my app to Amazon Webservices. I think the easiest way to do this is via Elasticbeanstalk.

I used Play2war to package my app
https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/

I was able to package it with

```
play war
```

According to the usage guide of play2war, I renamed my file to ROOT.war because i used Linux 32bit Tomcat7.

I also used the servlet 3.0 as described in the tutorial on play2war. (tomcat 7 -> servlet 3.0).

The file size is 31mb.

Every time I use Elasticbeanstalk, I get the same log.

```
2012-08-18 00:25 GMT+0200
WARN
Environment health has been set to RED
2012-08-18 00:25 GMT+0200
INFO
Launched environment: elosource. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
2012-08-18 00:25 GMT+0200
INFO
Your health check URL may be misconfigured. If your application does not respond to requests at http://elosource.elasticbeanstalk.com:80/, modify the health check URL to a valid path.
```

I tested it with Linux 32/64 bit , Tomcat7(servlet 3) and Tomcat6(servlet2.5). I always get the same result.

I also tried adding an extra html file for the health checker.

- What would you recommend me to do?
- What alternatives do I have to get my app running on ec2?
- Is there a guide that explains how I manually deploy my app to ec2 with all the needed dependcies, like mongodb, play etc?
- Also WAR files are relatively huge ~30mb, with my dsl 1k it is a real pain to upload such a lage file. Is there a way to only upload the changes with Elasticbeanstalk?

Comment: I don't undrstand there's no any error in your log, do why do you cało it error log ?

Comment: Sorry I was really tired yesterday. It should have been "Always the same error in the log"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I know this is not the straight answer to your question as I am not using beanstalk, but as you asked for it in one of the comments:

Here is how I **run my play2 app on a linux EC2 instance** with a jvm installed:

1. on your local machine, in your project directory, run `play dist`
2. send the `dist/yourapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` file (or whatever dist name you have
   configured) to the EC2 instance
3. ssh to your instance
4. unzip the dist file in the directory you want and `cd` there
5. run `chmod +x start`
6. run `nohup ./start &`

you now have your play2 application running natively on EC2, with websocket and all the cool stuff. I didn't have to configure anything special in play for that to work. I am using an RDS database configured as any other DB in play.

Clearly, it's a bit more hassle than beanstalk as you have to configure the server on your own and set up the autoscaling manually. But this is the best way that I have found to run play2 with all the features on AWS for now.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for. One question, I am using MongoDB do I have to manually install the dependencies on my linux instance or does play do everything for me?

Comment: I have to say that I haven't used MongoDB, so I can't be sure. Play should take care of getting the right libraries to compile and run, but you will have to have a mongoDB server running somewhere. If you plan to run this on EC2 too, then you will have to launch the server manually too (from what I understand, you can't run a mongoDB server on beanstalk anyway). However, you can get a hosted mongoDB server (e.g. mongolab), or you could just use amazon's own RDS, SimpleDB or Dynamo instead.

Comment: Also, I just found this: http://eugenedvorkin.com/mongodb-play-and-aws-developing-java-application-for-the-cloud/ It's clearly about play1 and the deploy of play2 might be different than for play1, but it might help you.

Comment: and, MongoDB has a page focused on installing on EC2: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Amazon+EC2

Comment: activator universal:packageZipTarball removes  step 5

Answer (score 3):

You should not package your application as a war, unless you are obligated to do or have a very good reason, as [you will loose great features](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/EPFZzWGm4Ro/r9tjH43x8H4J) of the framework (even with servlet 3.0 [you will miss websocket support](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/8-war-packaging#ticket-8-7)).

An option is to deploy your app through [dotCloud](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Deploying-to-dotCloud) service. The service runs [on top of Amazon EC2](http://docs.dotcloud.com/faq/) and enables you to choose your stack and scale vertically easily. Of course you have to decide if it is [worth the price](https://www.dotcloud.com/pricing.html), but you could test for free.

There as well other PaaS providers, that let you deploy play 2 applications:

- [Heroku](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ProductionHeroku)
- [Cloud foundry](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Deploying-CloudFoundry)
- [Openshift](https://github.com/opensas/play2-openshift-quickstart)

Comment: Yes thanks, atm I am using heroku, but i have one question, will servlet 3.1 fix ALL problems? Or will a native play2 client always be better? I would like to see something how to deploy a native play2 app to ec2. Could you recommend me some resources?

Answer (score 2):

`INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native...` is not the important part. Tomcat will start without it, and compiling it won't make your instance healthy. In fact, your `catalina.out` logging looks totally normal.

My guess would be Beanstalk's error messages are accurate: You've got a misconfigured health check URL. For whatever reason, you application just isn't returning a root document on port 80, a problem that could arise in a few ways. Try adding a static html or simple jsp page to your app's root directory (top-level in the WAR), and have Beanstalk check for that. Beanstalk's default port configuration should work (if I recall correctly it passes traffic via apache to tomcat and back, but I haven't looked in a while), but it couldn't hurt to check `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml` anyway just to see what's up.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. But I am still very new to webserver so it will take some time until I response again.

Comment: Just try an HTML page that says nothing more than "ok". That will at least isolate it to the health check or Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to upgrade to Play 2.3.x or newer, [Boxfuse](https://boxfuse.com) has native Play 2 support to address this.

You can now simply do `boxfuse run my-play-app-1.0.zip -env=prod` and this will automatically:

- create a minimal AMI tailor-made for your Play 2 app
- create an elastic IP
- create a security group with the correct permissions
- launch an instance of your app

All future updates are performed as **blue/green deployments with zero downtime**.

This also works with Elastic Load Balancers and Auto-Scaling Groups and the Boxfuse free tier is designed to fit the AWS free tier.

You can read more about it here: https://boxfuse.com/blog/playframework-aws

*Disclaimer: I'm the founder and CEO of Boxfuse*