# How do I put env_file in Dockerrun.aws.json file?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerrun.aws.json

I have env_file option in my docker-compose.yml file.

However, when I use container-transform, every option is translated into dockerrun, but env_file variable.

What is the efficient way to pass django environment variables to the docker deployed in elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Elastic Beanstalk environment properties in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149768/accessing-elastic-beanstalk-environment-properties-in-docker)