# Why I receive permission denied in Docker deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework-2.0, docker

I have created an application in [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) to host a play framework 2 app there using instructions from [this](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play2-on-beanstalk) project.

I have packaged the project exactly like Docker needs but when I upload the final zip to the application I receive a permission denied error in this flow:

- Environment update is starting.
- Deploying new version to instance(s).
- Successfully pulled dockerfile/java:latest
- Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
- **Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Fri Sep 12 23:32:44 UTC 2014: 2014/09/12 23:32:39 exec: "bin/my-sample-project": permission denied. Check snapshot logs for details.**

I have spent hours on this without any success.

This is the content of my root Dockerfile:

```
FROM dockerfile/java
MAINTAINER Cristi Boariu <myemail>
EXPOSE 9000
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/mytweetalerts"]
CMD []
```

Any hint how to solve this issue?

Comment: Make sure your script is executable.  Add `RUN ["chmod", "+x", "bin/mytweetalerts"]`

Comment: Also check that it is compiled for the right platform - if this is a binary (not a script)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I did to solve this same issue, though I'm not sure which part specifically solved it.

My DockerFile looks like:

```
FROM dockerfile/java
MAINTAINER yourNameHere
EXPOSE 9000 9443
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
# Make sure myApp is excutable
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "bin/myApp"]
USER daemon
# If running a t1.micro or other memory limited instance
# be sure to limit play memory. This assumes play 2.3.x
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/myApp", "-mem", "512", "-J-server"]
CMD []
```

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration for info on setting jvm memory.

My Dockerrun.aws.json (also required) looks like:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "9000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally my play application lives in `files/opt/docker` with the run script in `docker/bin`. All this is zipped up and sent to EB.

Answer (score 2):

Add a chmod command to make your file executable:

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "bin/myApp"]
```

So your Dockerfile will be:

```
FROM dockerfile/java
MAINTAINER Cristi Boariu <myemail>
EXPOSE 9000
ADD files /
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon", "."]
USER daemon
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "bin/myApp"]

ENTRYPOINT ["bin/mytweetalerts"]
CMD []
```