# Docker Error - "jq: error: Cannot iterate over null"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jq

So I'm trying to deploy a dockerfile on Elastic Beanstalk, but I can't get past this error - "jq: error: Cannot iterate over null".

```
Successfully built [myContainerId]
Successfully built aws_beanstalk/staging-app
[2015-01-29T10:35:59.494Z] INFO  [16343] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04run.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-01-29T10:36:05.507Z] INFO  [16343] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04run.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: command failed with error code 1: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04run.sh
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Thu Jan 29 10:36:05 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
at /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor/exec.rb:81:in `sh'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/executor-1.0/lib/executor.rb:15:in `sh'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/executable.rb:63:in `execute!'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/hook-directory-executor.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in run!'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `call'
from /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/beanstalk-core-1.1/lib/elasticbeanstalk/activity.rb:169:in `exec'
```

There aren't any other errors in the logs. My Docker container is successfully built, so it seems unlikely the error is coming from there.

My Dockerrun.aws.json looks like :

```
   {
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "blah",
    "Update": "false"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm banging my head against a wall with this one, nothing I change seems to affect it and googling hasn't been of any help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 77):

If others are looking for how to avoid the `Cannot iterate over null` error in their own `jq` commands, add a question mark after `[]`. For example

```
echo '{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "blah",
    "Update": "false"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }
  ]
}'|jq -c '.Volumes[]?|[.HostDirectory,.ContainerDirectory]'
```

where `[]` was replaced with `[]?` does not display the error.

From the manual:

```
.[]?
    Like .[], but no errors will be output if . is not an array or object.
```

Comment: This is not supported in jq 1.3; unfortunately, ubuntu 14.04 ships 1.3. anyone know a workaround for jq 1.3?

Comment: @JDS @nobody, See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622937/267455)  - since `jq` is a single, self contained binary, you can just overwrite your apt version with one from a newer release, such as [version 1.5](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.5)

Answer (score 37):

The problem is that your Dockerrun.aws.json file is missing the `Volumes` property.

The 04pre.sh script uses the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) tool in order to query the JSON file.

Specifically, it runs the following command on your file, which yields to an error:

```
$ jq -c '.Volumes[] | [.HostDirectory, .ContainerDirectory]' < Dockerrun.aws.json
jq: error: Cannot iterate over null
```

Specifying an empty "Volumes" array should resolve the error.

Answer (score 13):

Note that an Elastic Beanstalk deployment to the Docker platform can fail with the "jq: error ... Cannot iterate over null..." error message in various phases of an Elastic Beanstalk deployment, for various different reasons. This can include your application (Docker container) quitting or erroring on startup.

Although this particular reported occurrence of the problem may have been specific to a missing "Volumes" property in Dockerrun.aws.json, your problem may not be. If you get this error, then the best way to go about diagnosing the problem is to download your full EB logs and check the diagnostics in the following log file /var/log/eb-activity.log.

If the problem was caused by your application failing to startup then you'll find the error in /var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/unexpected-quit.log.

Comment: To give some idea of alternative causes of this error message: mine was due to running out of memory.

Comment: This is truly the best answer. Also, for anyone new to this like me, to check logs you do this on the CLI: `eb logs`.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was already checking if the result was empty or not after running my `jq` command so I simply added `try` to the beginning of my query:

**Before**

```
$myJson | jq -r '.data[0].tags.version[] | select(startswith(""chart-"")) | sub(""chart-"";"""")'
```

**After**

```
$myJson | jq -r 'try .data[0].tags.version[] | select(startswith(""chart-"")) | sub(""chart-"";"""")'
```

Then if the result is empty I act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was caused by `ADD` in Dockerfile instead of `COPY` instruction. Changing it fixed the issue.