# Upgrading jq to 1.5 on Ubuntu

Tags: json, ubuntu, upgrade, jq

So it reads [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/):

jq 1.5 is in the official Debian and Ubuntu repositories. Install using sudo apt-get install jq.

yet:

```
$ sudo apt-get install jq
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jq is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

AND:

```
$ jq --version
jq version 1.3

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

What am I missing?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: yes. It upgraded my chrome, but jq is still the same (1.3)

Comment: Try with `apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>`, to make sure, what's the package that is not upgraded?

Comment: Had already tried. No luck:

$ sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade jq
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jq is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: This might help, choose the jq 1.5 binaries for your architecture and try to install them. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: yes, downloading the binary and very rudely replacing /usr/bin/jq with the new binary did the trick. I was hoping in something more ubuntista but thanks.

Comment: You should probably accept Juuso Ohtonen's answer below

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I ended up here when googling on why my Debian 8 instance does not upgrade `jq` 1.4 to 1.5.

Here's my solution for anyone struggling with Debian 8 jq: Download `jq` from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases and copy it manually over the currently installed jq. In my case:

```
wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64
chmod +x jq-linux64
sudo mv jq-linux64 $(which jq)
```

Comment: Upvoted because it worked, not because I liked it :)

Answer (score 4):

You're using Ubuntu LTS. The latest version of Ubuntu does have jq 1.5.

Comment: So how can easily get jq 1.4 or 1.5 for ubuntu 14.04 LTS ?

Comment: @Nati Your question has already been answered on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103320/install-packages-from-newer-release-without-building-apt-pinning

Comment: This may be the answer, but I don't understand it. It seems like "master apt-get" is the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing the correct repo: http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/vivid/universe/j/jq/install/index.html

Comment: No he has Ubuntu 14 and not 15.