# Bash match 2 json files based on common id

Tags: json, bash, jq

I wish to match 2 json files based on common id
I've tried using awk, jq and the npm json package in quite a lot of different ways but nothing have gotten close to working.
The 2 json files are not sorted and do not contain all the same entries. they contain the common networkId, I only want the output to contain the entries from file2.
Hope somebody can help!
Here's an example.

file1.json:

```
[
  {
    "customerId": "id1",
    "networkId": "L_653021545945744804"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "id2",
    "networkId": "L_653021545955724805"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "id3",
    "networkId": "L_655051945958724557"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "id4",
    "networkId": "L_655567989968735408"
  }
]
```

file2.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "networkId": "L_653021545945744804"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "networkId": "L_655051945958724557"
  }
]
```

Wanted output:

```
[
  {
    "customerId": "id1",
    "name": "a",
    "networkId": "L_653021545945744804"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "id3",
    "name": "b",
    "networkId": "L_655051945958724557"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task for `INDEX`, `JOIN` and `add`:

```sh
jq '[JOIN(INDEX(.networkId); input[]; .networkId; add)]' file1.json file2.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "networkId": "L_653021545945744804",
    "customerId": "id1"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "networkId": "L_655051945958724557",
    "customerId": "id3"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hdBL13XInA)

Comment: upvoted, because this solves my similar problem where I want to include the recs from the 1st set that don't have a corresponding id in the second set: jq '[JOIN(INDEX(input[]; .id); .[]; .id; add)]' [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/V7Yxs8Svw9)

Comment: remark: Oracle Linux 8 with EPEL 8 installed didn't support jq 1.6 which seems to be necessary for JOIN(). The upgrade wasn't trivial and I managed it following this advice: [Upgrading jq to 1.5 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42622937/4335480)